# Set Zend\Form Error Messages from Controller

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

this is probably a very simple task, but currently I'm failing horribly at it. I just want to add a custom error to my form when my authentication fails.

**What i tried**

```
$form->setMessages(array(
    array('password' => $this->failedLoginMessage)
));
```

**Unexpected Result**

```
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($form->getMessages());
array(0) {}
```

If i understand the code correctly this should attach an error message to the password element. Actually looking at the setMessages i thought attaching a single-dimension array should have been enough, but it needs the 2nd dimension, too :S I'm just stuck on that simple task, sigh :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My comment as answer, as you've requested:

You can also set error messages to an element directly, using:

```
$form->get('elemName')->setMessages(array('message1', 'message2', ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, read the code correctly... Correct usage as following:

```
$form->setMessages(array(
    'formElementName' => array(
         // multiple error messages possible...
    )
));
```

Comment: You can also set error messages to an element directly, using `$form->get('elemName')->setMessages(array('message1', 'message2', ...));`

Comment: @DanielM Provide this as an alternate answer and this will be the selected one. I was constantly looking for $form->getElement... good to know simple get() will do.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this lines of code.

```
$form->getElement('controlname')->setErrors(array('Your custom error'));
```

in case the message not showing in your page check removeDecorator method used in zend form. if there is use addDecorator method befor writing error message code line.