# zend password confirmation password match not working

Tags: zend-framework

Below snippet does not alert the " The passwords do not match "  message.

```
$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
$password->setDecorators($elementDecoration);
$password->setLabel('Password')
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

/* password confirmation - just set the token section to the password field name */

```
$confirmPswd = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('conf_password');
$confirmPswd->setDecorators($elementDecoration);
$confirmPswd->setLabel('Confirm Password:');
$confirmPswd->setLabel('Confirm Password:');
$confirmPswd->setAttrib('size', 35);
$confirmPswd->setRequired(true);
$confirmPswd->addValidator('Identical', false, array('token' => 'password'));
$confirmPswd->addErrorMessage('The passwords do not match');
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following URL for the confirmation password.

http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/creating-a-simple-password-confirmation-field/

This will surly help you.

Also check the following link:

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/11/23/how-to-setup-different-error-messages-for-each-zend-form-element-validator/

Also check this:

[Set Zend\Form Error Messages from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896624/set-zend-form-error-messages-from-controller)

Comment: Above snippet which i pasted is took from that blog only, the think is, i want to display the custom message in the web. this details is not provided in that site

Comment: I hope you have posted the code from this blog. Have you tried this code. This will work fine.

Comment: how the message will display when we simply adding the above code, should i print some variable to display that message know. plz advise

Comment: I have added the answer. check it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the identical validator on email addresses.  To add it to the form, I use the following code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'confirm_email',
            array(
                'label'=>'Confirm Email Address',
                'required'=>true,
                'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
                'validators'=>array(array('EmailAddress'),
                                    array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages'=>'Confirm email address is required.')),
                                    array('Identical', false, array('token'=>'email', 'messages'=>'The email addresses provided do not match.'))),

        'class'=>'thirdCol'));
```

I use flash messenger to display the errors

```
foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->flashMessenger->addMessage($error);
            }
```

If you're trying to get a javascript alert when the form is submitted, I think you have to code it yourself.  In your form, use something like

```
$this->setAttrib('onsubmit', 'return checkRegistration();');
```

And have the checkRegistration function be an ajax call to some controller/action that returns the errors to be alerted. If you're looking to return json or something similar

```
$this->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

will disable layouts and views so all that is returned is what you echo.

Hope this helps.